# Como obter o valor da propriedade <version> no pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven

Eu preciso obter o valor da versão atual da aplicação em várias partes do código. A priori eu pensei em criar uma classe contendo a versão:

```
public class Version {
    public static String getVersion(){
        return "0.1.0";
    }
}
```

Mas deve existir uma forma melhor de fazer isto (creio eu).

Eu vi que o Java possui uma [especificação sobre versionamento](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/versioning/spec/versioning2.html#wp89936), mas não entendi se é para o mesmo propósito que estou querendo.

Bom, como estou usando o Maven e existe a propriedade `<version>` no arquivo de configuração, pensei que na hora de dar manutenção ficaria mais fácil atualizar somente esta propriedade usá-la em todo o projeto.

A questão é: É possível obter essa propriedade? Se sim, como fazer?
Se não, poderiam me dar alternativas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O [Maven Resources Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) permite realizar substituições de variáveis do maven nos arquivos (*resources*) do projeto.

Esse plugin faz parte do plano de execução padrão do maven nas fases `process-resources` e `process-test-resources`, portanto o que você precisa fazer é instruir o plugin a substituir as variáveis durante essas fases.

Seguindo o exemplo da documentação, você simplesmente precisa adicionar a configuração a seguir:

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <name>My Resources Plugin Practice Project</name>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
      ...
    </resources>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Então qualquer arquivo no diretório especificado vai ser processado pelo Maven. Você poderia então criar um `txt` ou `properties` contendo a versão:

```xml
versao=${project.version}
```

Dessa forma, o Maven se encarrega de colocar a versão correta quando empacotar o projeto.

Se houver outros arquivos no projeto pode ser melhor evitar que eles sejam desnecessariamente ou indevidamente processados. É possível  especificar várias tags `<resource>` contendo tags `<include>` e `<exclude>` para especificar quais arquivos deseja processar e quais devem permanecer intactos.

Exemplo:

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*.properties</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
      ...
    </resources>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: Obrigado Luiz, farei alguns testes. Aquele `Package` do Java também serve para versionamento?

Comment: @renan A especificação de versionamento do Java é interessante e contém informações importantes se você está implementando uma biblioteca ou módulo que é utilizada com vários componentes e dependências de diferentes versões. Por exemplo, você pode ter um jar com as interfaces da API na versão `1.0` e um jar de implementação da API na versão `1.0.10`, portanto o [manifesto](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html) do jar iria conter diferentes versões de especificação e de implementação. Entretanto, para casos mais simples essa informação é irrelevante.

Comment: O [Maven Archiver Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/manifest.html) pode gerar essas informações para você. Então você poderia ler essas informações durante a execução carregando o arquivo `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` do jar.